# KeyError: 1 python for loop iteration error

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, url, keyerror

I am writing a code that takes the URLs from an only URL column of a df (`list_links`) and saves the main domains in a list (`links`). Converting them from "https: //www .theguardian .com/us-news /etc" to "www.theguardian.com" for further analysis. But I can't make the iteration work to convert the next link in `list_links`.

```
f=0
clinks=[]

if f<=len(list_links):
  for l in list_links:
    domain = urlparse(list_links[f]).netloc
    clinks.append(domain)
    
  f=f+1
  

clinks
```

It gets stuck on list_links[0].

> ['www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> 'www.theguardian.com',
> ...

How can I make the iteration work? Helpp

Comment: `f` is redundant in this code. remove all references to it (the `f=0`, `if f<=len(list_links)` and `f=f+1`) and change `list_links[f]` to `l`

Comment: `f=f+1` is indented at the wrong level. If you want `f` to represent the index of the list, then `f=f+1` is indented one level too little.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is a little odd and can be simplified:

```py
clinks = []

for list_link in list_links:
    domain = urlparse(list_link).netloc
    clinks.append(domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You are using `f=f+1` outside the `for` loop, make it work inside the loop.

```
for l in list_links:
    domain = urlparse(list_links[f]).netloc
    clinks.append(domain)
   f = f+1
```

Solution 2: `f` is completely useless if used for the index, because in `for` loop `l` itself is used as index, go for:

```
for l in list_links:
    domain = urlparse(l).netloc
    clinks.append(domain)
```